# dbeaver icon is missing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, icons, dbeaver

my dbeaver icon is missing. my OS ubuntu 20.04 || can only be opened with terminal by running this command : `dbeaver-ce`

.any idea to fix this?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem.Can someone plz help?

Comment: i solved with this https://askubuntu.com/a/141247